# What is the purpose of messages like "You have mail in /usr/spool/mail/root"?

Tags: unix, aix

I am working on sn AIX6.1 box, but my question  probably applies to all Unix platforms. Unfortunately I haven't found any satisfactory answers on the web.

My question:

Whenever I log in to my AIX box (or, say, any Unix machine), I see a message like,

```
You have mail in /usr/spool/mail/root
```

Can anyone tell me a good explanation for this message, like what is its purpose, and on what events this message is displayed to user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's shell mail checking.  If the file named by the shell variable MAIL - defaulting to something like /var/spool/mail/username - is larger than the last time it checked, then it echoes that message to let you know that well, new mail has arrived.

Answer (score 1):

This is a remainder from old CLI-only Unix times. When there were no GUI email clients yet, and the user logged in to his account on a computer which had an associated mailbox (in our school we have these also), it came handy to notify the user of having unread emails.